# X-bee and accelerometer: problem streaming data

Tags: accelerometer, xbee

Hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

I am currently trying to create a wireless accelerometer using two x-bees (series 1). The accelerometer module is set up so that the x,y,z channels are connected to the DIO0, DIO1 and DIO2 channels on an x-bee explorer. The device is all powered through the 3.3V input on the explorer by a 3.7V (110mAh) li-po battery which is also connected to a usb li-po charger.

I have setup the x-bees within X-CTU and there is no problem communicating between them. DIO0, DIO1 and DIO2 are all set to ADC and i have set it using several different sampling frequencies. I have noticed within the terminal window that when moving the device both DIO0 and DIO1 appear to remain constant (FF 03 from memory) and only DIO2 seems to vary within each data packet. If i change the setup at any one time to only transmit the data from one of the three channels at a time, they all change with movement.

Any chance you might be able to guess where ive managed to mess it up. I am assuming that the wiring and power between the accelerometer and the explorer is fine given it works when only displaying one channel at a time but my experience with these things is limited so im stumped with where to go with it now... Just wondering if the x-bee requires more power for the ADC for all three channels and the it might just need more power to the device to work?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the accelerometer doesn't put out more than 1.2V (03 FF is the max value for XBee's ADC). Make sure to use pull-up/pull-down resistors if your sensor requires them.